# How to apply coefficients of independent variables to update a model

Tags: linear-regression

- I'm working on a multilinear regression project in which I am attempting to predict the potential ability of football players.
- For my independent variables (`x`), I am using about 30 attributes that describe a player's ability. These include `passing`, `attacking_finishing`, `movement_sprint_speed` etc. These are all rated on a scale of `0-99`.
- For my dependent variable (`y`), I am using `potential` (ability), also on a scale of `0-99`.
- I have done some feature importance analysis on a group of players (in a single position) that performed to a high level in a given time period in order to determine what strengths they had in common.

An example of a few attributes and their coefficients (from the feature importance analysis):

```
positional_versatility has a coefficient of 0.0041
weak_foot has a coefficient of -0.0421
skill_moves has coefficient of 0.0010
```

- I now want to apply these coefficients to an updated model, so that it effectively gives weightings to each attribute - a higher coefficient will equate to a higher weighting.
- So, given the three attributes above, for example, a player with a greater `positional_versatility` rating will effectively get a boost to their predicted `potential`, because `positional_versatility` has a higher coefficient.

**My question**: how do I apply the coefficients to an updated model in order to achieve the attribute weightings as described above?

Please let me know if you need any clarification, thank you.

Comment: This seems like ordinal regression not linear regression. Is that the case? The coefficient is applied to the data to get the predicted y. Are you thinking this is now scoring? Where you trained a model with some data and now you want to apply the model to new data and get the predictions?

Comment: hi Craig, I'm unfamiliar with ordinal regression but I'm pretty sure my project is a multiple linear regression problem

Comment: sorry, what exactly do you mean by 'scoring'?

Comment: The target is a scale of 0-99. Is 2 twice as good as 1? Is 90 ninety times better than 1? What if the model predicts 1.5? Or -3? Or 105.234? An unconstrained linear regression (multiple or multivariate typically means using many X independent variables) can predict any number and has distance. Stock price of 40 is twice 20. House price of 800000 is twice 400000. The target above is ordinal - there is an order but not a defined distance, and it is constrained. If you use linear regression but be prepared for other than whole numbers between 0 and 99.

Comment: Scoring is using the model to score new data. When you build a linear regression, you can examine the coefficient for inference (how much does feature each contribute relative to others, etc). When you want to predict on new data, then you take the trained model and send it the new data. In this case, each coefficients is multiplied by the feature, then summed to give you the prediction.  The 0-99 in this case.